# MAX IF Array Formula Returning Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following data in Excel Sheet "Sheet1":

```
     A           B
1    MY_FIELD    YEAR
2    333         2010
3    354         2012
4    100         2013
5    145         2010
```

I am attempting to return the maximum value of MY_FIELD for each year in another sheet. In this other sheet I have

```
    A      B
1   YEAR   MAX_VALUE
2   2010
3   2011
4   2012
5   2013
```

Into B2 I enter

```
=MAX(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5=A2,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5))
```

with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter as an array formula.

This is returning zero. I understand this occurs if the value searched for is not found, but I can see the value searched for, A2, is 2010, which is present in the array Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5.

What is the error in my formula or my approach?

Comment: Check to make sure that the years are not dates formatted `yyyy` while the other is just the number.

Comment: That's fixed it thank you. If you place as an answer I'll accept.

Comment: on phone, feel free to post your own answer as to what  the problem was and what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The years in Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5 were formatted using TEXT(DATE,"YYYY"). This returns text fields. The formula requires strictly numbers.

Copying the data in Sheet1!$B$1:$B$5, pasting as values, and setting all to number, returns in the formula working.